# Action-Target Not Being Called Custom UIControl In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently having an issue trying to execute an action-target on a Custom UIControl that I was creating. I have never created a UIControl and wanted to begin by creating one with multiple radio buttons. The only issue is when I try to do so I am unable to call the function in the action-target call. Initially thought the issue was that I was using the UIControl in a custom tableview cell that I was creating but when I place the UIControl somewhere else it still will not fire that action-target.

```
import UIKit

class RadioButtonScaleControl: UIControl {
var firstButton:UIButton

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

override init(frame:CGRect) {
    firstButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    super.init(frame:frame)


    self.generateButtonLayout()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    firstButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    super.init(coder:aDecoder)


    //     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    self.generateButtonLayout()
}

  func generateButtonLayout() {
      firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(20,70,26,23)

    let radioButtonClicked = UIImage(named: "BtnRadioActive") as UIImage
    let radioButtonDefault = UIImage(named: "BtnRadioInactive") as UIImage

    firstButton.setImage(radioButtonDefault, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    firstButton.setImage(radioButtonClicked, forState: UIControlState.Selected)


    firstButton.addTarget(self, action:"buttonClicked:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)


}

func buttonClicked(sender:AnyObject)
{
    println("button clicked!")
    //sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
}
```

So above I never get to the buttonClicked function. I try to click on the button but no action ever is taken. Below is the custom tableview cell I call my
  UIControl from :

```
import UIKit

   class RadioButtonsCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
       var curRadio:RadioButtonScaleControl
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    curRadio = RadioButtonScaleControl(frame:CGRectZero)
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    curRadio = RadioButtonScaleControl(frame:CGRectZero)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.addSubview(curRadio)
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state

}

}
```

Has anyone ever run into a similar issue? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've never subclassed UIControl before, so apologies if this is a stupid suggestion: do you need to add `firstButton` as a subview of your `RadioButtonScaleControl`: ie. add `self.addSubview(firstButton)` to `generateButtonLayout()`?

Comment: I just read somewhere that when you try to create your own control you are not allowed to add the UI Components into your UIControl. Not sure how true that is but that might explain why I seem to be having issues. I tried a different approach where I just add a UIButton in interface builder to my custom cell. I then add an action to my subclassed tableviewcell class. However I am still unable to get the target-action to execute? At this point I assume the target action needs to have the delegate point to the view controller and doesn't like being in a custom view.